# Wired-OR does not get synthesized

Tags: vhdl, synthesis, vivado

I want to have two combinational processes driving one signal in wired-or style. Each process can drive 'Z' or '1' value to the signal and there is a global pull-down to 'L'.

Vivado 2017.1 synthesis 'optimizes' my code to drive a constant 0 to the output port. Why does this happen? How do I work around this issue?

**Code:**

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity test is
    port(
        input_0 : in    std_logic;
        input_1 : in    std_logic;
        output  : out   std_logic
    );
end entity test;

architecture rtl of test is
    signal s_output : std_logic;
begin
    output  <=  to_X01(to_bit(s_output));

    process(input_0)
    begin
        s_output    <=  'Z';

        if input_0='1' then
            s_output    <=  '1';
        end if;
    end process;

    process(input_1)
    begin
        s_output    <=  'Z';

        if input_1='1' then
            s_output    <=  '1';
        end if;
    end process;

    s_output    <=  'L';
end architecture rtl;
```

**Synthesis result:**

```
WARNING: [Synth 8-3917] design test has port output driven by constant 0
```

[image]

Comment: My guess is that Vivado will not synthesise tri-state logic for your FPGA (or perhaps any FPGA). It is a bad idea to use tri-state logic inside any chip. Why do you want to do this? A normal OR will do the same and will not suffer from the disadvantages that tri-state logic does.

Comment: i think you need an event trigger (or clock but in this case a clock isn't the best trigger), you could trigger on rising input or falling input.

Comment: IEEE Std 1076-2008 16.8.2.4.2 Interpretation of the forcing and weak values ('0', '1', 'L', 'H', FALSE, TRUE) "...This standard makes no restriction as to the interpretation of the relative strength of values." You're at the tender mercy of the Vivado Synthesis User Guide chapter on HDL Coding Techniques, Tristates, coding examples.

Comment: You cannot use a tristate bus type inside of your FPGA. There is no such thing like a pull-up pull-down transistor in the FPGA. `s_output    <=  'L';` will synthesize as a ground connection and not a resistor, as you see. In an FPGA everything is realized in look-up-tables and registers.

Comment: @JHBonarius Yes, of course I know that tristates will not be instantiate in my fabric. However, the code posted above can theoretically be translated by the synthesis tool to proper boolean logic. I have used similar constructs in the past a few times and never experienced any issues.

Comment: In C++ they would call this UD: undefined behavior. You are describing something in code which is not officially described in the synthesis user guide, but the synthesis software tries to solve it for you. Sometimes (often?) it fails. As rule-of thumb: don't use anything but '0' and '1' (except for FPGA outputs with tristate option)

Comment: "I know that tristates will not be instantiate in my fabric." In HDL *never* tempt fate! One of the basic rule is: *If you are not sure about what you will get, don't use the construct.* "can theoretically be translated". Theoretically C = A/B can be synthesised but no tool supports it.

Comment: @Oldfart Maybe some time ago, but just try it in for instance Vivado (i used 2018.1): it actually synthesizes. (271 LUTs on a Kintex 7 for 16-bit unsigned integer division).

Comment: @Oldfart Now tested Quartus (18.0).. also synthesizes. ;) 154 ALMs on Cyclone V